# Open Source Javascript Calendar Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, sharepoint-calendar, html

I am attempting to use the open source calendar available at fullcalendar.io in a web part of mine. I have the correct dependencies...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

and I initialize the calendar like...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

}); </script>
```

This all works perfectly when I use my own .html file and test it, however when I deploy it to Sharepoint and try to insert the web part containing the script, it will only display the buttons of the calendar.

**Calendar working in separate html...**

[image]

**Calendar not working as web-part...**

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there an obvious reason why I can't use this open source JS calendar in SP?

Comment: Do you have an element in the DOM with an ID of `calendar`?

Comment: @Submits Yes I do I have a <div id='calendar'></div> in the body.

Comment: It seems fullcalendar.js has a function called `computeRangeAs` which takes in three parameters, `unit`, `start`, `end`. It seems either `start` or `end` are undefined. Sorry I can't be more help, but perhaps this will help you debug.

Comment: @Submits It seems 'end' is undefined, but the function computeRangeAs is supposed to be able to handle a null value in end, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it displaying... Turns out that using a `div` with ID 'calendar' on a sharepoint site causes the display to mess up, simply used an `h1` tag instead.